# Transition from Docker to Podman - how to do persistent multiple compose configurations?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, podman, podman-compose

I've seen questions like https://serverfault.com/questions/964862/podman-method-to-convert-docker-compose-files-to-systemd-unit-files that address converting specific `docker-compose.yml`-Configurations to `systemd` units, which is fine I suppose. But we are transitioning from having around 120 configurations, and I really don't want to set up 120 new `systemd` units just to have our services come back up after a reboot.

I was under the impression that since the advent of `podman` v3, transition from existing `docker-compose.yml` setups was relatively seamless, but with Docker, our services, when configured with appropriate `restart:` policies, would just come back after a reboot. This seems like a huge time sink, which usually means I'm on the wrong approach. What is the go-to in the world of `podman` to having many, potentially dynamic, services that I want to survive reboots ?